# In paragraph how to find strings between the given strings using php?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, match

[image: In paragraph how to find strings between the given strings using php ?]

save as siva.txt

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt SIVA ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodoconsequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse

cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur PRABU sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor

in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. xcepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, SIVA sunt in culpa qui

officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum PRABU

Answer (score 1):

It's always the same, really:

```
SIVA((?s).*?)PRABU
# look for SIVA
# ((?s) ... ) forms a capturing group where the dot matches everything
# .*? is lazy
# match until PRABU is found
```

Use the first group and see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/CA2pcD/2/).

---

In `PHP`:

```
$regex = '~SIVA((?s).*?)PRABU~';
if (preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[1]);
}
```

This yields

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodoconsequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse

cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur 
    [1] =>  sunt in culpa qui

officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer given by Jan with regular expression. I tried with custom coding. For the record here we go.

```
$text = "Lorem ipsum dolo ... it anim id est laborum PRABU";
//$text should have all the text.
$keys = array('SIVA','PRABU');
$startPos = 0;
$endPos = 0;
$arr = [];
while($startPos < strlen($text)){
    $startPos = strpos($text, $keys[0], $startPos);
    if($startPos === false){
        break;
    }
    $startPos += strlen($keys[0]);
    $endPos = strpos($text, $keys[1], $endPos);
    $data = substr($text,$startPos, $endPos - $startPos);
    array_push($arr,$data);
    $endPos += strlen($keys[1]);
}
```

Here is the result

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```